# Python Easygui | Как убрать тип All files?

Tags: python

Я использовал модуль Easygui, чтобы выбрать файл.

Функция fileopenbox работает, но при выборе выбран тип All files. Как его убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: помогло снять вопрос-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вызове  fileopenbox явно определите default. По умолчанию это как раз All files из текущей директории.

```
easygui.fileopenbox(msg=None, title=None, default='*', filetypes=None, multiple=False)
```

https://easygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html